# Regex.Matches not returning expected

Tags: c#, regex

Using `Regex.Matches` I'm under the impression that you would enter something as such:

```
    private static int CheckForWordMatch(string offer, string item)
    {
        string pattern = @"\b(" + item + ")\b";
        int count = 0;
        count = Regex.Matches(@offer, pattern).Count;
        return count;
    }
```

Test parameters:

```
offer = AK47HyperBeastFieldTested
item = AK47HyperBeastFieldTested
```

I am looking for the EXACT word match so that if the item were to be, say, "AK47HyperBeast" it wouldnt return a match count of 2.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to use a verbatim string literal with the second `@)\b`. Your `")\b"` is treated as a `)` and a backspace character.

```
string pattern = @"\b(?:" + item + @")\b";
```

[See C# demo](http://ideone.com/5RMW3k):

```
string offer = "AK47HyperBeastFieldTested";
string item = "AK47HyperBeastFieldTested";
string pattern = @"\b(" + item + @")\b";
int count = Regex.Matches(offer, pattern).Count;
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Some suggest using `(^|\b)` and `(\b|$)` - this is redundant since `\b` (word boundary) already matches at those positions.

If your `item` may start or end with a non-word character, but you still need a whole word match, use

```
string pattern = @"(?<!\w)(" + item + @")(?!\w)";
```

Also, note that you only need the round brackets if you plan to use alternations (e.g. `\b(word|another)\b`). You can remove them safely if you test just 1 word at  a time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and concise explanation. And to add, so all I actually missed was one `@` verbatim string indicator! I already cleaned the `item` string and the `offer` string to only contain letters, thankyou for the further information however.

Comment: @MattGarnett: You are welcome, it is easy to forget about the `@` sign when concatenating string literals.

Comment: And surely I forgot back then (9 years ago) to use `Regex.Escape()`. Also, now, I'd recommend adaptive word boundaries, i.e. `string pattern = @"(?!\B\w)(" + Regex.Escape(item) + @")(?!\B\w)";`

Answer (score 0):

`\b` is word boundary which you dont have in `offer`.instead use

```
string pattern = @"^\S*(" + item + @")\S*$";
```

Comment: No, word boundaries match at the beginning and end of strings. `\S` is also wrong, because that matches any non-whitespace character. Did you mean `\s`? That'd be wrong, too, since more than whitespace is considered a word boundary. In C#, [the \b anchor specifies that the match must occur on a boundary between a word character (the \w language element) and a non-word character (the \W language element)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#WordBoundary). You can simulate this for beginning word boundary with `(?<^|\W)` and ending word boundaries with `(?=$|\W)`.

Comment: No, word boundaries match at the beginning and end of strings. `\S` is also wrong, because that matches any non-whitespace character. Did you mean `\s`? That'd be wrong, too, since more than whitespace is considered a word boundary. [In C#, the \b anchor specifies that the match must occur on a boundary between a word character (the \w language element) and a non-word character (the \W language element)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#WordBoundary). You can simulate this for beginning word boundary with `(?<=^|\W)` and ending word boundaries with `(?=$|\W)`.